# Encryption of a file in kotlin returns HEADER_TOO_LONG

Tags: kotlin, encryption, rsa, public-key

i'm porting an old java android app to a kotlin approach.
What i'm trying to achieve here is to encrypt a file using a .der file

Here what i did so far, as you can see i basically adapted the code to work in a kotlin base

Kotlin

```
    val encodedKey : ByteArray = ByteArray((publicKeyFile.length()).toInt())
    val publicKeyFileIS = FileInputStream(publicKeyFile)
    publicKeyFileIS.read(encodedKey)

    // create public key
    val publicKeySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey)
    val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
```

Java

```
    byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)publicKeyFile.length()];
    FileInputStream publicKeyFileIS = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
    publicKeyFileIS.read(encodedKey);
    
    // create public key
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
```

The problem is that in the Java app, the encryption works like a charm, but in kotlin one when i try to launch

> generatePublic

I get

error:0c00007b:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:HEADER_TOO_LONG

Any hint on how to solve this?

EDIT: my .der has this content

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA1pHArx4xPIMGDI53itcMEx1hNXRmllyTmrsB
dFNjRVeXwHrfKtNVruUR12SU1PeM7jQ4fmHJLcy4BBWgYpktylLM9xyVyXVqsqOZPuvnvqt/mUABXAVW
odkW/oANbSgbBnvLwVmuX+dNnMKIp1RMY/xEstYx4HaVUsClaSZpxuMdkfOYP9tQs5uNbR5RyWE6+4JE
2fkhpwK82HIX94wGvSoiNCgBcXQPjYZf1TnZHifv7FbuRiZxjzdKgtqgBT8tUW8m5Mjz4ktN8YkHov8a
XRhbkXbBdN8LBjxyDs3M7dm3W3/u3pLN3WtkDXuREGNQNUi3/PU93JK9IzuUDWwF2wIDAQAB
```

Edit 2:
I tried to put the method readBytes() and logging a base64 of the .der, which is fairly different

```
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
```

and the code:

```
val encodedKey = FileInputStream(publicKeyFile).readBytes()
        val encodedString: String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedKey)
        println("publicKeyFile keyBase64 : $encodedString")

        // create public key
        val publicKeySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey)
        val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
```

Edit 3:

here some info about the gradle file

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

And the stacktrace:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c00007b:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:HEADER_TOO_LONG
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:290)
W/System.err: at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:54)
W/System.err: at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:357)
W/System.err: at it.lynx.gmelibrary.utils.FileEncryption.saveKey(FileEncryption.kt:95)
```

Comment: Perhaps you have an example public key file that triggers this behavior. If so, edit your question and add the contents of this file.

Comment: i have the .der file, but the content is crypted, also if i Try to change it to a Base64 format and try to decode it, i can't see what's inside

Comment: Actually the key should be valid if it can be imported from the Java code. However, you could upload the key to https://lapo.it/asn1js. This will automatically Base64 encode a DER key, which you can post.

Comment: Note also that `read(byte[] b)` is not guaranteed to read all bytes. So on the Java side it's better to use [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) and on the Kotlin side [`readBytes()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/read-bytes.html).

Comment: **What is the _type_ of `publicKeyFile` in both cases?** Java `new FileInputStream(x)` can take either a `String` containing the filename or a `File` object _representing_ the filename, but `.length()` produces very different results (and wrong in the first case).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 publicKeyFile  is a File in both sides

Comment: @Topaco edited with the .der content

Comment: On my machine the posted key can be imported (after conversion to DER) with the posted Kotlin code. So I can't reproduce the issue. You could Base64 encode the imported key `encodedKey` and compare it with the key you added in the question to check if the key import is the problem. If the key is incomplete, you could try `val encodedKey = FileInputStream(publicKeyFile).readBytes()`.

Comment: @Topaco i edited the code but, i have the feeling i'm missing something

Comment: If the string MO+/vQ... is Base64 decoded, then many 0xefbfbd sequences are contained, which corresponds to the replacement character in Utf8. Possibly the data was converted to a string using UTF8, which would corrupt it.

Comment: Yes, Topaco is right. At some point, some "binary" data was turned into a `String`; it was corrupted at this point, as many bytes turned into �. Then that string was encoded with UTF-8 (and finally encoded with base-64).

Comment: ok, but still i don't get where this error should be caused, assuming the code are the "same"

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your response because you didn't tag me with `@`. Are you encountering the error when running on Android? OpenJDK and other runtimes don't use OpenSSL, but perhaps Android's JCE does. Can you provide more complete error message or stacktrace and more information about the runtime environment where you see this problem?

Comment: @erickson i'm debugging it on an android 8 device, both codes.
I'm also editing my question with some gradle info and stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the "ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:HEADER_TOO_LONG" error when I try to parse the corrupted "MO+/vQEi ... AgMBAAE=" content (after base-64 decoding).

I believe the problem is that your Kotlin is reading a different (bad) file than your Java. The public key file should be identical in both cases, and should be DER-encoded (that is, "binary", not base-64–encoded).

You could verify this by putting the same base-64–encoded key as a string literal in both code samples and decoding it at runtime, instead of loading from a file. If both samples work, you'll know it's a data problem, not a code problem.

I can *almost* convert your public key into the corrupt "MO+/vQEi ... AgMBAAE=" form by decoding the DER-encoded key as if it were text using UTF-8, then re-encoding the text with UTF-8. The difference is in the number of replacement characters that show up.

It looks like the UTF-8 decoding (where the content was first corrupted) may not have been done with Java, but something that handles malformed inputs a little differently. A malformed sequence like "… C0 AF …" looks like the code point U+004F (`'O'`) incorrectly encoded as two UTF-8 bytes. (That's wrong because it must be encoded as a single byte, 0x4F.) Java outputs a replacement character for each byte. It looks like the decoder you used outputs just one replacement character for the invalid sequence.